# Segmentation Fault when print errno for shm_open in Linux

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, printf, shared-memory, errno

I am practising using shared-memory in Linux by C, here is my code for a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SIZE_OF_MEMORY sizeof(int)
#define SHARED_MEMORY_NAME "GDM123456"

int main()

{
    int shm_fd = shm_open(SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777);

    if(shm_fd == -1)
    {
        printf("failed to open shared memory\n");
        printf("shm_open error, errno(%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE_OF_MEMORY) == -1)
        printf("failed to set size of memory\n");
    int * i_ptr = mmap(NULL, SIZE_OF_MEMORY, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    *i_ptr = 1000;

    if (munmap(i_ptr, SIZE_OF_MEMORY) == -1)
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    shm_unlink(SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);
    shmctl(shm_fd, IPC_RMID, 0);
}
```

And since the SHARED_MEMORY_NAME("GDM123456") I specified has already been occupied in the Linux Server so the shm_open is supposed to return -1 and set the corresponding value to errno (I know the name has been occupied because this is a default value given by a lecture example which lots of students are going to run in our Linux Server and if I change the Name to something else the "if-failed block" just won't be triggered).

However, when I tried to run the code it turned out to be:

```
psyhq@bann:osc$ gcc sharedMemory.c -o sharedMemory -lrt    
psyhq@bann:osc$ ./sharedMemory
failed to open shared memory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It looks like a segmentation fault occurred when I tried to print the errno out, so I wonder how this situation can happen?

Here is the result from my gdb:

```
psyhq@bann:osc$ gdb sharedMemory
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /lhome/psyhq/osc/sharedMemory...done.
(gdb) r  
Starting program: /lhome/psyhq/osc/sharedMemory 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
failed to open shared memory

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78586e4 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
(gdb) b 24
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40095d: file sharedMemory.c, line 24.
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /lhome/psyhq/osc/sharedMemory 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
failed to open shared memory

Breakpoint 1, main () at sharedMemory.c:24
24          printf("shm_open error, errno(%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
(gdb) p errno
$1 = 17
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78586e4 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

PPS: Here is the version information of the Linux Server I run my code on:

```
psyhq@bann:osc$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017
```

Comment: It "seems". So, what *is*? Use a debugger to be sure.

Comment: I didn't get this compiled without including some headers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I ran the gdb for my code...I have added the result to my question...and I am new in gdb/Linux-c stuff...from my understanding, the value of errno is correct and the Segfault is caused by printf...but I still have no idea about how this can happen...could you help me?

Comment: @wildplasser maybe you are using -std=c99? I don't know but it works well in our Linux Server...I am going to add the version information of our server to the question anyway.

Comment: No, just the default (`std=gnu90`)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry..it is a stupid question, I have figured out the reason. It is all due to that I forgot to include string.h as a header...so the strerror() cannot work properly to return the information corresponded to the errno value..I used gcc without -std=c99 here and the complier on the linux server didn't give me any warning related to the missing header..my fault, and this do teach me a lesson anyway.